# How long would Jupiter take to "chase over" Saturn?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume Jupiter orbits around the sun every 12 years and Saturn take 30 years approximately, and their orbits are at the same plane. Since Jupiter orbits the sun faster, it would chase over Saturn (at between Saturn and sun) per X years.

What is the step to find X?(note: I'm not asking how long they would return to same position together, so X is not 60)

I tried:

12t=30t-2pi

18t=2pi

t=2pi/18

But I'm sure it is not correct because t must be greater than 12

Comment: what has been tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Jupiter orbits with an angular velocity$$\omega_1=\frac{2\pi}{12 }\text{rad/y}$$
and Saturn at $$\omega_2=\frac{2\pi}{30}\text{rad/y}$$
Their relative angular velocity (the rate at which Jupiter chases Saturn) is the difference
$$\omega = \Delta\omega=\frac{\pi}{10}\text{rad/y}$$
So if the planets are separated by an angle $\theta$, the time needed for Jupiter to overtake Saturn would be (assuming constant velocity)

$$t=\frac{\theta}{\omega}.$$

For $\theta=2\pi$ you get the desired result

$$X=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version:

By making a full circle ( we'll assume a circular path for ease) in 12 years, Jupiter travels 30 degrees/year around the circle. Saturn, takes 30 years to go around the circle, progressing 12 degrees per year. So the difference between the two, is 18 degrees per year. As 360=20 * 18,  it will take this difference adding up for 20 years for the difference to equate to a multiple of 360, at which time Jupiter will be passing Saturn.